# Receiving file in Java Server from Android

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc

I have existing code in Spring controller to accept file upload

```
CommonsMultipartFile file = ...;
file.getContentType(); // image/jpeg
file.getOriginalFilename(); // Penguins.jpg
```

The above works fine for user submission from browsers. Now I am required to create similar service for user upload from Android.

This is what I have so far on my backend

```
byte[] imageDataBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(file);
// TODO : get the file extension
```

How can I get the uploaded file extension from Android ?

Comment: If you can get the filename, you can split it along the "."

Comment: means this must be done on the Android app, is that correct ?